# Cross Browser Support question

Tags: cross-browser, opera

I am trying to make my own article publishing site.
You can make articles, edit articles , view articles...

All this stuff needs some scripts and I have everything , I think so.

Problem is in Opera.
Other browsers work fine but Opera, sometimes, I repeat not every time, only sometimes and always randomly, cannot understand the logic why, but for example if I have 2 tinyMCE textareas, it starts 1 editor, and another textarea is left without transformation it to tinyMCE.

Another Example I have article with lots of pictures in it, and while saving they are processed with php file, and after process user views edited article.

So other browsers are fine, but opera do not like to wait untill php finishes work with pictures and it fires empty article.

Other browsers fire normal articles....

Is there anything I must know, maybe I missed some known bug with opera , or what ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but instead of tinyMCE (users can easily create really problematic markup without knowing) have you considered PageDown http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown - as used here on SO? The live preview shows the result to the user, but the code keeps their markup nice and semantic.

Comment: Is there "picture uppload from your pc" feature in that editor ? Or I must find it somewhere else ?

Comment: also I think it does not support embedded videos

Comment: I think (not seen the latest) the image upload is the same as the SO field below - as for embedded videos, I suggest (whatever you choose in the end) that users pass the code through validifier: http://www.validifier.com although I've also had problems with videos in TinyMCE (and Joomla). See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279611/how-to-embed-a-video-into-github-readme-md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in old jquery and ajaxSubmit plugins. I've updated them and everything works fine.