# How to add screenshot to READMEs in github repository?

Tags: github, markdown

Is it possible to place a screenshot in README file in a GitHub repository? What's the syntax?

Comment: The correct solution to this is to use relative references, per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11916467/1633251 (see the comment with the link to a new github doc on how to do this). The short answer is to use `[Read more words!](docs/more_words.md)`

Comment: Most solutions propose to point to the repo itself. What about if you want to avoid binaries in the repo (even in a separated branch, as proposed) and you want to store it in an external place? Any good practices? A gist maybe (IDK if gist can be binary or just text)? creating another repo "myproject-assets" for the project "myproject"? Any external popular image-place similar to the de-facto standard of youtube for uploading videos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add images to README.md on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Comment: https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Comment: March 2021: simple drag&drop: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66465892/6309)

Comment: Not an answer.. just a suggestion https://dillinger.io/ this online makedown editor has good options

Answer (score 1005, accepted):

If you use Markdown (README.md):

Provided that you have the image in your repo, you can use a relative URL:

```
![Alt text](/relative/path/to/img.jpg?raw=true "Optional Title")
```

If you need to embed an image that's hosted elsewhere, you can use a full URL

```
![Alt text](http://full/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
```

GitHub recommend that you use **relative links** with the `?raw=true` parameter to ensure forked repos point correctly.

The `raw=true` parameter is there in order to ensure the image you link to, will be rendered as is. That means that only the image will be linked to, not the whole GitHub interface for that respective file. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189356/how-to-add-screenshot-to-readmes-in-github-repository/10189374?noredirect=1#comment94874283_10189374) for more details.

Check out an example: https://raw.github.com/altercation/solarized/master/README.md

If you use SVGs then you'll need to set the sanitize attribute to `true` as well: `?raw=true&sanitize=true`. (Thanks @EliSherer)

Also, the documentation on relative links in README files: https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes

And of course the markdown docs: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Additionally, if you create a new branch `screenshots` to store the images you can avoid them being in the `master` working tree

You can then embed them using:

```
![Alt text](/../<branch name>/path/to/image.png?raw=true "Optional Title")
```

Comment: Well, I added the official docs on relative links, but I'm unable to find some repo that uses them, if you have suggestions, I'll be happy to help since the whole point is helping more people, not staying in the scope (my mistake here).

Comment: @Paul , here's an example repository doing just that! https://github.com/Tarrasch/zsh-bd

Comment: You can also link the image to somewhere other than the raw image file using the following syntax: `[![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg?raw=true)][http://example.com/]`

Comment: https://github.com/altercation/solarized is the rendered version of the example above, in case that helps anyone.

Comment: Is it possible to put an image, that's actually a link?

Comment: Yes, you can use a full URL too, if that's what you mean. Check the answer please.

Comment: The example doesn't seem to have relative links anymore.

Comment: I have done it like thousand time but still I forgot syntax every time.

Comment: When you say `/relative/path/to/img.jpg`, isn't that an absolute path due to the leading slash?

Comment: what does mean by `Alt text`?

Comment: Does it supports `.pdf`?

Comment: If you store the image in another branch, the proposed solution /../<branch name>/path/to/image.png works only with the GitHub README, and not when working with the README file locally. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670565/display-github-readme-screenshot-stored-in-a-different-branch-both-on-github-an)

Comment: It looks like your example site stopped using relative links.

Comment: Note that `?raw=true` does not work for SVG! Just remove that parameter and it'll work.

Comment: @Paul I have implemented your solution and it's worked like a charm. But I am facing one issue, gif is playing only once. While in my local machine it is playing on repeat mode. I don't know why GitHub plays it only once. Any Help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: @Paul "GitHub recommend that you use relative links with the ?raw=true parameter to ensure forked repos point correctly." Is this still relevant/valid? I could not find it in the GitHub documentation.

Comment: @kelvin, the `raw=true` parameter is there in order to render the image the GitHub path points to, not the GitHub interface. Try and see the difference: https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/img/screen-html-dark-th.png vs https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/img/screen-html-dark-th.png?raw=true. The first URL will show you the GitHub interface and the image, while the second will only show you the image. The relative links are still useful when cloning/forking repos, so yes you should use relative paths with that parameter, but they are two different concepts.

Comment: @gati, I am sorry, I do not have any idea on your issue.

Comment: For SVG to work add sanitize (i.e. `?raw=true&sanitize=true`)

Comment: Excellent concision, you just taught me about the raw=true param. For future travelers, my issue was related to how Google Cloud Storage actually serves its images. To make it work I had to grab the rendered long-url from Google, see my answer below.

Comment: @Paul do you know how resize the image

Answer (score 87):

Even though there is already an accepted answer I would like to add another way to upload images to readme on GitHub.

- You need to create issue in your repo
- Drag and drop in the comment area your image
- After link for the image is generated insert it to your readme

More details you can find [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180104120901/http://www.solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/28/awesome-github-tricks/)

Comment: I'm interested how long images loaded this way will live. Does github perform some images cleanup? Like, "if this image not referenced from any github issue, I can safely remove it"...

Comment: @Artin probably only when the issue is deleted completely. Closed issues stick around forever as they serve a very important role in documentation and debugging

Comment: The hyperlink provided in this answer seems fishy

Comment: @EMT The domain appears to have changed over the years and is expired / dormant. I've updated the link to an archive.org mirror. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 56):

I found that the path to the image in my repo did not suffice, I had to link to the image on the `raw.github.com` subdomain.

URL format `https://raw.github.com/{USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY}/{BRANCH}/{PATH}`

Markdown example `![Settings Window](https://raw.github.com/ryanmaxwell/iArrived/master/Screenshots/Settings.png)`

Comment: Downvoting this because of @sorens comment on the accepted answer. It's bad to specify absolute bath since it won't work well on forked repositories. (Or if you rename your repo, or if github changes domain name, etc. etc.)

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck: There's one good reason to use absolute paths imho: If the readme.md is used in other places as well, for example, as a Doxygen main-page. Relative links won't work then.

Comment: @Ela782 although, on a further note, that *ought* not to be an issue for software that's ripping README files *specifically from GitHub*; such software should know to resolve relative URLs properly. [npm does](https://github.com/npm/npm-www/issues/517), for example.

Comment: how to  link to the image on the `raw.github.com` subdomain ? where to upload the image file ?

Comment: @Saif raw.github.com is just a reflection of what is committed to your github repository. Just commit the image to your repository and follow the URL format specified.

Comment: @LinusUnnebäck That's exactly why I'm trying to use relative URLs. However, I'm storing the images in an `assets` branch, and I'm having issues to make it work with both the GitHub README, and with the README file locally. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670565/display-github-readme-screenshot-stored-in-a-different-branch-both-on-github-an)

Answer (score 54):

**JUNE 3, 2020 : WORKING ANSWER-**

1. Upload your image to [postimage.org](https://postimages.org)
2. Copy  **Github-Markdown-Url** after uploading Image
3. Insert in your ReadMe

Comment: You are the only one whose answer was useful to me

Comment: It's a fine answer, but just be aware you're depending on that service to exist forever. It makes no guarantees about not disappearing one day. Neither does GitHub, but enough important projects and people depend on it that I feel safe that I'd at least be provided backups / dumps before it went down. Also, I don't know what its terms and conditions say, but again, because a lot more people would have pored over GitHub's T&C, I trust it more.

Comment: ...and also if the image is on GitHub, the image and the readme will disapear together.

Comment: @AndrewCheong for any mission critical assets, reliance on a single third party is never a good idea.  GitHub or any other service should NOT be _relied_ on to provide disaster recovery backups.  Ultimately the assets should be protected through multiple backup options.  At least with `git` backing up to multiple stores is pretty simple.

Comment: GitHub no longer allows links from postimage. If you follow this procedure, you'll receive this error in the JavaScript console:


`Refused to load the image 'https://i.postimg.cc/...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: github.githubassets.com media.githubusercontent.com camo.githubusercontent.com identicons.github.com avatars.githubusercontent.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com objects.githubusercontent.com objects-origin.githubusercontent.com secured-user-images.githubusercontent.com/ user-images.githubusercontent.com/ ...`

Answer (score 25):

One line below should be what you looking for

if your file is in repository

```
![ScreenShot](https://raw.github.com/{username}/{repository}/{branch}/{path})
```

if your file is in other external url

```
![ScreenShot](https://{url})
```

Comment: suggest using the relative link of the image file, see [Relative links in READMEs - Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes)

Comment: -1 for the reason given by @shaobin0604; the official docs recommend using relative links when linking to a file in your own repo, so that the link points to the right place when forked.

Answer (score 19):

The markdown syntax for displaying images is indeed:

```
![image](https://{url})
```

**BUT:** How to provide the `url` ?

- You probably do not want to clutter your repo with screenshots, they have nothing to do with code
- you might not want either to deal with the hassle of making your image available on the web... (upload it to a server... ).

So... you can use this [awesome trick](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/28/awesome-github-tricks/) to make github host your image file. TDLR:

1. create an issue on the issue list of your repo
2. drag and drop your screenshot on this issue
3. **copy the markdown code that github has just created for you** to display your image
4. paste it on your readme (or wherever you want)

http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/28/awesome-github-tricks/

Answer (score 16):

Much simpler than adding URL
Just upload an image to the same repository,
like:

`![Screenshot](screenshot.png)`

Comment: not able to resize the image using `![Screenshot](screenshot.png)`

Answer (score 13):

add this to README

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="/screenshots/screen1.jpg" width="400px"</img> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

From March 2021, this is now supported:

> ### [Attaching files to markdown files](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-03-03-attaching-files-to-markdown-files/)

> You can now attach files, including images, to markdown files while you're editing them in the web.
>
> This works just like file attachments in issues and pull requests and supports the same file types.
>
> **Just drag and drag, click and select, or paste.**
>
> [image: Drop to upload a gif -- https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/7900087/109347520-25045d00-7828-11eb-9609-ee96b396eb65.gif?ssl=1]
>
> Note: If you add an image to a markdown file, anyone can view the anonymized image URL without authentication, even if the markdown file is in a private repository.
> To keep images private, serve them from a private network or server that requires authentication.
> For more information on anonymized URLs see "[About anonymized image URLs](https://docs.github.com/articles/about-anonymized-image-urls)".

Comment: How to customize the width and height of the screenshots?

Comment: @NeerajaGandla once imported, check https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109 or https://gist.github.com/MichaelPolla/a65ac84286ab523603e64549f9850223

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1->Markdown way**

```
![Alt Text](https://raw.github.com/{USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY}/{BRANCH}/{PATH})
```

**Method 2->HTML way**

```
<img src="https://link(format same as above)" width="100" height="100"/>
```

or

```
<img src="https://link" style=" width:100px ; height:100px " />
```

*Note*-> If you don't want to style your image i.e resize remove the style part

Answer (score 4):

Add `![ScreenShot](screenshot.png)` in the readme markdown as mentioned by many above. Replace screenshot.png with the name of the image you uploaded in your repository.

**But here is a newbie tip when you upload the image (as I made this mistake myself):**

ensure that your image name does not contain spaces. My original image was saved as "Screenshot day month year id.png". If you don't change the name to something like contentofimage.png, it won't appear as an image in your readme file.

Comment: Easiest method by far! I was just about to make this entry myself when I read down far enough to see this excellent answer. They only let me upvote once.

Answer (score 4):

### For me, the relative path worked out very well.

**How I did this:**
In my current md file where I wanted to use a picture from another directory, I used a relative path like this - consider following points.

md file loc: `base dir -> _post -> current_file.md`

& picture file loc which I wanted to use: `base dir -> _asset -> picture_to_use.jpeg`

What the statement I used was on `current_file.md` file:

```
![your-pic-caption-name](../_asset/picture_to_use.jpeg)
```

Note - before this, I was using direct `_asset` but Ideally, it so starts from `../_asset/and-so-no`

reference - https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-readmes

Answer (score 2):

I googled a few similar questions and did not see any answers with my problem and its quite simple/easy solution.

## Google Cloud Storage - a slightly different approach to images in READMEs

Here goes: like the OP, I wanted an image in my Github README, and, knowing the Markdown syntax for doing so, typed it in:

```
![My Image](https://storage.cloud.google.com/${MY_BUCKET}/${MY_IMAGE}
```

You need to complete the actual substitutions above (e.g. MY_IMAGE=image.jpg) for this to work.

> But, wait...failure--there's no actual rendered photo! *And the link is exactly as given by Google Storage!*
>
> [image: screenshot of failed Github image upload]

### Github `camo` - Anonymous Images

[Github hosts your images anonymously](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-anonymized-image-urls), yay! However, this presents an issue for Google storage assets. You need to get the generated url from your Google Cloud Console.

I'm sure there's a smoother way, however, simply visit your given URL endpoint and copy the long URL. Details:

#### Instructions

1. Visit your storage console: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/${MY_BUCKET}?project=${MY_PROJECT}
2. Click on the image you'd like to display in Github (this brings up the "Object Details" page)
3. Copy pasta that URL (the one starting with `https` not `gs`) into a new browser tab/window
4. Copy pasta the new generated URL -- it should be longer -- from your new browser tab/window into your Github README file

Hopefully this helps speed up and clarify this issue for anyone else.

Comment: FYI -- It appears something is changing on the Google or Github side of things. I've had some images in READMEs failing via this method, and some working as of afternoon March 28, 2020. YMMV here!

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps:
this worked for me

1. Create a new issue on GitHub.
2. Drag and drop an image onto the comment field or upload a photo.
3. Wait for the upload process to finish.
4. Copy the URL and use it in your Markdown files on GitHub (use that generated URL in your repository's readme).

Comment: Best to just add it to your repo, not indirectly using an upload from an issue. This way it can be versioned and changed more easily over time as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a directory(folder) in the root of your local repo that will contain the `screenshots` you want added. Let’s call the name of this directory `screenshots`. Place the  images (JPEG, PNG, GIF,` etc) you want to add into this directory.

[Android Studio Workspace Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1BPM.png)

Secondly, you need to add a link to each image into your README. So, if I have images named `1_ArtistsActivity.png` and `2_AlbumsActivity.png` in my screenshots directory, I will add their links like so:

```
 <img src="screenshots/1_ArtistsActivity.png" height="400" alt="Screenshot"/> <img src=“screenshots/2_AlbumsActivity.png" height="400" alt="Screenshot"/>
```

If you want each screenshot on a separate line, write their links on separate lines. However, it’s better if you write all the links in one line, separated by space only. It might actually not look too good but by doing so GitHub automatically arranges them for you.

Finally, commit your changes and push it!

Answer (score 0):

To me the best way is -

1. Create an new issue with that repository on github and then upload the file in gif format.To convert video files into gif format you can use this website http://www.online-convert.com/
2. Submit the newly created issue.
3. Copy the address of the uploaded file
4. Finally in your README file put ![demo](COPIED ADDRESS)

Hope this will help .

Comment: How is it different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252663/1570104 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add image in repository from upload file option then in README file

```
![Alt text]("enter image url of repositoryhere")
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a New issue by clicking on the green button in the upper right corner. Take a screenshot of whatever you need and paste it into the issue message (CMD+V on Mac or CTR+V on Windows).

Answer (score -1):

My image had space in the name, e.g. `Pasted image 20221006123035.png`, and that was causing a problem from me, and I lost some time fixing it. If someone has the same issue, then here are the steps

- I uploaded the image via upload option
- Then clicked on the image in the file browsing UI of the website.
- The image is opened in the browser. From the browser's URL I copied the url of the image. You can copy the whole path, or relative to your `.md` file
- Now insert that link to the .md file like `![overview](Pasted%20image%2020221006123035.png)`

Answer (score -5):

With the images located in `/screen-shots` directory. The outer `<div>` allows the images to be positioned. Padding is achieved using `<img width="desired-padding" height="0">`.

```
<div align="center">
        <img width="45%" src="screen-shots/about.PNG" alt="About screen" title="About screen"</img>
        <img height="0" width="8px">
        <img width="45%" src="screen-shots/list.PNG" alt="List screen" title="List screen"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't figure out to center an image in the README - which your answer contains, so thanks!

Comment: I found this answer helpful since it enables you to set the dimensions of the image