# Image not showing up in README.md on GitHub

Tags: image, url, github

I am trying to add an image to the **README.md** in my repository using markdown below:

```
![ScreenShot](https://github.com/i-saumitra/Voice-controlled-MP3-Player/blob/master/screenshot.jpg)
```

But the image is not showing when I visit my repository. 
Instead the link to the image is showing up. Clicking the link will open the image in new window.

I have also tried using relative path:

```
![ScreenShot](screenshot.jpg)
```

But this is giving page not found error.

What is the correct markdown to display image in **README.md**

Both **README.md** and image file are in same path/directory.

What is the correct way to display an image in github README.md?

Complete content of README.md file is as below:

```
Voice-controlled-MP3-Player
===========================

A MP3 player which accept voice command like PLAY, PAUSE, FORWARD, etc. Using C# and Microsoft Speech API.

![ScreenShot](https://github.com/i-saumitra/Voice-controlled-MP3-Player/blob/master/screenshot.jpg)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add images to README.md on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Comment: All of a sudden, this "problem" has resurfaced. The images that were rendering previously don't show up. This is not only in my repos but others as well. What gives?

Comment: Never mind! They seem to work now...I even made an issue of it on another repo! https://github.com/arshadkazmi42/first-issues/issues/87

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319849/4393351

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### Updated content

Since January, 30th 2013, GitHub now supports relative links in markup documents.

This means that your code `![ScreenShot](screenshot.jpg)` would now work flawlessly.

As pointed by @Brad, this may also ease a scenario where the images are different in two branches, but bear the same. In that case, switching from one branch to another, would dynamically switch the image in the rendered view, thus without requiring any change to the Readme content.

- **[Blog post announcement](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files)**
- **[Help article](https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes)**

### Previous answer when GitHub wasn't supporting relative links

You have to use the raw url format. In your case that would be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-saumitra/Voice-controlled-MP3-Player/master/screenshot.jpg

This means that the correct markdown would be the following

```
![ScreenShot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-saumitra/Voice-controlled-MP3-Player/master/screenshot.jpg)
```

Using this in a `.md`file on github will display the following picture ;-)

[image: ScreenShot]

### Update following your comment

> where is this officialy documented that we have to use raw...i couldn't find it anywhere

This URL format is an undocumented feature of the GitHub site. This means that it could change later. If that ever happens, in order to "rediscover" the new format, click the **Raw** button when displaying a image. This will "open" the image in your browser. Copy the URL and Voilà!

[image: raw]

**Note:** Although the repository is no longer on hosted on GitHub, I've updated the urls to reflect the new **[GitHub policy](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-04-25-user-content-security/)** regarding user content

Comment: For others finding this, Github now supports relative linkes: https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes

Comment: This is no longer a good solution.  GitHub now supports linking to an image with a relative path:  `![alt text](doc/image.png)`  The benefit here is that you can use other branches and know that you have the right version of the images in your documentation.

Comment: @Brad I'm storing the images in an `assets` branch, and I'm having issues to make relative paths work with both the GitHub README, and with the README file locally. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670565/display-github-readme-screenshot-stored-in-a-different-branch-both-on-github-an)

Answer (score 42):

You really should use relative urls. That way they'll work better for private repos as well.

```
![ScreenShot](/screenshots/latest.png)
```

supposing your repo has latest.png inside the screenshots folder.

~B

Comment: I agree, preferably make it relative to an image within the repo :-)

Comment: It is especially true that Github occasionally change the raw file path, notably recently from "http://github.com/user-name/repo-name/raw/" to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/repo-name/". Use relative paths so you don't need to check often if your repo image links are broken.

Comment: You can also use `<img src="../<branch>/screenshot.jpg?raw=true" width="100" height="100" />` If you want to support retina support by providing an image that is e.g. 200*200px ;)

Comment: How can I display images from a private repo inside of the repo related public GitHub page?

Answer (score 18):

For relative URL's to work with images, wrap it inside the paragraph tag.

I was facing the problem, especially when working with the single image.

Example:

```
<p>
    <img src="relativePath/file.png" width="220" height="240" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

An extension to previous answers...

The image would not show for me when the line:

```
![ScreenShot](/image.png)
```

Was directly below a `<h2></h2>` line and I needed to add an empty line between them.

Hopefully this saves someone some time!

Comment: This was the same for me. Make sure you have an empty line above the code snippet specifying the image.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I would update this for 2019 as I had trouble figuring this out for myself. I uploaded my images to a repo on GitHub, and then used the raw url of the image to import it into my markdown file. To get the raw url, click on the specific image link in GitHub so you are on the page for that specific image. To the top right of the photo, there are two buttons, "Download" and "History". If you click "Download", it takes you to that raw url with the picture taking up the full screen. Copy that url, and then paste it like this in your markdown file:

`![image description or alt text](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/i-saumitra/Voice-controlled-MP3-Player/master/screenshot.jpg)`

The button used to say "Raw" not "Download" so I hope this helps people find it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant to previous answers.  I have the same question as the OP - I was directed here and it didnt help me.  I hope I can help add light to this question however -  as it covers the possibilities of why images does not render  in `README.md` file.

The `issue` I encountered is that the file name `README.md` file is written as `readME`

Not only its missing `.md` its also written differently.

Apparently, we should not rename the `README.md` file.  It has to be the original name of that file in order to render the images or gifs you want to upload on github `README.md` page.   Hope this helps someone, in rare of occasions, just like I did.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with "Copy path" and in some locations this was working and in others it didn't.

[image]

In the cases it didn't, I copied the permalink and used it instead.

Comment: This one worker for me. Copied link would sometimes have "?raw=true" appended in the end, and the image will not be rendered without it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file extensions because `.png` is not the same as `.PNG`.

Also use `/` instead of `\` while specifying the file path.

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing the markup you are using and without knowing the real path of the image. Can you provide it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the case of the file extension. They have to match (either capital or lowercase). If you have `my_image.PNG` in your root directory and you add `![screenshot](/my_image.png)` to your README file, it will not work. For some reason, Windows likes to capitalize file extensions sometimes. Unfortunately, Git does not recognize extension case so if you try to fix it by just changing the file name, you won't be able to commit the changes to the repo since Git will think everything is up to date. So you either have to update README.md or do some workaround like moving the file out of the directory, making a commit, then editing the file name then moving it back and doing another commit.

Answer (score 0):

Side note, when using reStructuredText use:

```
.. image:: /screenshots/latest.png?raw=true
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn;t work when there are any html tags just above the line where image is being imported. You can try removing the html code or add some blank lines for the image to show on Readme.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to help someone who is still having issues with image rendering in README.md:

If your image is named `Some Name.png` and you are trying to attach it in the README.md like `![Some Name](relative/path//res/Some Name.png)`, it won't work. The image has to be saved **without any spaces** in the file name.

So `Some_Name.png` with `![Some Name](relative/path//res/Some_Name.png)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while adding image in readme file but the following didn't work for me:

1. `[alt text](relativePath/file.png)` even though my file extension and path were correct
2. adding in the `<p>` tags like

> ```
> <p>
>    <img src="relativePath/file.png" width="220" height="240" /> 
> </p>
> ```

The following worked for me:
Drag and drop the image in readme.md that added the following piece of code:

```
![alt-text](https://github.com/user/repo/assets/asset_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to add a `<br>` to return a line in order for the image to show on mine. This discovery was inspired by the comment in this thread to leave a blank line after a  tag.