# How can one display images side by side in a GitHub README.md?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to show a comparison between two photos in my README.md which is why I want to display them side-by-side. [Here](https://github.com/saadq/Sublime-Color-Schemes#solarized-ocean) is how the two images are placed currently. I want to show the two Solarized color schemes side by side instead of top and bottom. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I created a little web-tool that allows you to add and align images without writing the markup yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790440/2477619

Comment: link from question doesn't work

Answer (score 613, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of solving this is using the [tables](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/) included in GitHub's flavored markdown.

To your specific example it would look something like this:

```
Solarized dark             |  Solarized Ocean
:-------------------------:|:-------------------------:
![](https://...Dark.png)  |  ![](https://...Ocean.png)
```

This creates a table with Solarized Dark and Ocean as headers and then contains the images in the first row. Obviously you would replace the `...` with the real link. The `:`s are optional (They just center the content in the cells, which is kinda unnecessary in this case). Also you might want to downsize the images so they will display better side-by-side.

Comment: `![](https://...Ocean.png)` between those Square Braces you can add Alt-Text that is displayed when you hover over the image.

Comment: This solution is better if you want to put more images on the same line on github. I managed to put 4 on the same line with this solution but only 3 with wigging's solution.

Comment: Wonderful! Works with Bitbucket as well. (Well, I can vouch at least that it works on their pull request screen.)

Comment: Too bad this puts a border around your images.

Comment: @EpicDavi : in the context of your code, how do you downsize images within the table?

Comment: could you please give some hint on how to make this 4 columns?

Comment: @MonaJalal you can just follow the same pattern. The [docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/organizing-information-with-tables) have an example of 3 columns

Comment: Works for me. The text of the first table header cell must not have spaces before it. Otherwise the table is not rendered at all.

Comment: I think [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61340219/10458409) accurately addresses the question

Comment: Note that to hide the title of each column, you can use the special character "⠀" (which is not a whitespace)

Answer (score 376):

This will display the three images side by side if the images are not too wide.

```html
<p float="left">
  <img src="/img1.png" width="100" />
  <img src="/img2.png" width="100" /> 
  <img src="/img3.png" width="100" />
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, it should have more upvotes! I used `<p align="middle">` to align the images on the center.

Comment: Is it possible to add a title to each of the images?

Comment: This is perfect! As it allows to specify the sizes of the images.

Comment: I prefer to specify the image as a percentage of the total width, e.g. `width="32%"` when aligning 3 images

Comment: Is there a similar way to use the same technique to align the images vertically (above/below each other)?

Comment: How can I add image captions/titles with this method?

Comment: I would also add `<img align="top" src="..."` for all images.

Comment: Best solution out there and adjust the size helps for large images

Answer (score 194):

You can place each image side-by-side by writing the markdown for each image on the same line.

```
![alt-text-1](image1.png "title-1") ![alt-text-2](image2.png "title-2")
```

As long as the images aren't too large, they will display inline as demonstrated by this screen shot of a README file from GitHub:

[image: inline images]

Comment: doesnt quite work for me. one of the (relative) images is a gif

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel It doesn't matter whether your images are gifs or not. I successfully placed two gifs side by side with this method.

Comment: doesn't work for large (too wide) images

Comment: if the images are different sizes, you can balance the scale using %. 
`![alt-text-1](image1.png "title-1" =20%x) ![alt-text-2](image2.png "title-2" =75%x)`

Comment: Also works with html img tags!

Answer (score 70):

Similar to the other examples, but using html sizing, I use:

```
<img src="image1.png" width="425"/> <img src="image2.png" width="425"/>
```

Here is an example

```
<img src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/28580/kablam-Number-Animals-1.png" width="200"/> <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/71101/two.svg" width="300"/>
```

[image] [image]

I tested this using [Remarkable](https://remarkableapp.github.io/linux.html).

Comment: I used `<img height="350" hspace="20"/>` as a separator between images in an issue ([wigging's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31571776/3124150) didn't work).

Comment: This works with larger images too that need resizing to fit on one row.

Answer (score 49):

This solution allows you to add space in-between the images as well. It combines the best parts of all the existing solutions and doesn't add any ugly table borders.

```html
<p align="center">
  <img alt="Light" src="./light.png" width="45%">
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <img alt="Dark" src="./dark.png" width="45%">
</p>
```

The key is adding the `&nbsp;` non-breaking space HTML entities, which you can add and remove in order to customize the spacing.

You can see this example live on GitHub at [transitive-bullshit/nextjs-notion-starter-kit](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/nextjs-notion-starter-kit#dark-mode).

Comment: I think this is the best one - if you have larger images and don't want to mess about with pixel sizes. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 35):

This is the best way to make add images/screenshots of your app and keep your repository look clean.

Create a `screenshot` folder in your repository and add the images you want to display.

Now go to `README.md` and add this HTML code to form a table.

```html
#### Flutter App Screenshots

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Screen Page</td>
     <td>Holiday Mention</td>
     <td>Present day in purple and selected day in pink</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745092.png" width=270 height=480></td>
    <td><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745125.png" width=270 height=480></td>
    <td><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745139.png" width=270 height=480></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

In the `<td><img src="(COPY IMAGE PATH HERE)" width=270 height=480></td>`

** To get the image path --> Go to the `screenshot` folder and open the `image` and on the right most side, you will find `Copy path` button.

You will get a table like this in your repository--->

[image]

Answer (score 20):

For markdown table syntax see:

https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables

---

Quick summary:

To quickly understand the syntax used in other answers, it helps to start from a more complete intuitive and easier to remember syntax, and then a minimalized version with the same result.

Basic example:

```
| Header A       | Header B       |
| -------------- | -------------- |
| row 1 col 1    | row 1 col 2    |
| row 2 column 1 | row 2 column 2 |
```

Same result in a more minimalist form (cell widths can vary) :

```
Header A | Header B
--- | ---
row 1 col 1 | row 1 col 2
row 2 column 1 | row 2 column 2
```

And more related to the question: side by side images with labels on top:

```
label 1 | label 2
--- | ---
![](https://...image1.png) | ![](https://...image2.png)
```

( use `:---` , `---:` , and `:---:` for (text) alignment in the column, respectively: left, right, center )

Answer (score 10):

If, like me, you found that @wiggin answer didn't work and images still did not appear in-line, you can use the 'align' property of the html image tag and some breaks to achieve the desired effect, for example:

```
# Title

<img align="left" src="./documentation/images/A.jpg" alt="Made with Angular" title="Angular" hspace="20"/>
<img align="left" src="./documentation/images/B.png" alt="Made with Bootstrap" title="Bootstrap" hspace="20"/>
<img align="left" src="./documentation/images/C.png" alt="Developed using Browsersync" title="Browsersync" hspace="20"/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

## Table of Contents...
```

Obviously, you have to use more breaks depending on how big the images are: awful yes, but it worked for me so I thought I'd share.

Comment: Thank you! Also `hspace` is a neat little trick if there is not enough space between the pictures. Didn't know github actually parses that.

Answer (score 9):

To piggyback off of @Maruf Hassan

```
# Title

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Screen Page</td>
     <td>Holiday Mention</td>
     <td>Present day in purple and selected day in pink</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745092.png"></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745125.png"></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="screenshots/Screenshot_1582745139.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

`<td valign="top">...</td>` is supported by GitHub Markdown. Images with varying heights may not vertically align near the top of the cell. This property handles it for you.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to have 3 images aligned left/center/right all on the same line, so it automatically adds suitable space between them:

```html
<p align="center">
      <img src="..." align="left">
      <img src="...">
      <img src="..." align="right">
</p>
```

This is what it looks like for my real use case [here](https://github.com/alexmojaki/futurecoder/blob/140f045057e850291a40e2b4dd3ad68160f36ece/README.md):

[image]