# How do i set two images in in same line at hexo blog?

Tags: next.js, hexo

I just build a blog for myself, build up by hexo and next.
Today i have known how to set one picture by this :

```
![image description](img's url)
```

But by this way i cant put two images on same line.It loos like this:
image1
image2
And this is what i want
image1 image2
I have checked disable fancybox and tried to use this (just write them at the same line):

```
![image description](img's url)![image description](img's url)
```

They are both no effect.

Comment: Since Hexo supports GitHub Flavored Markdown, does this answer your question: [How can one display images side by side in a GitHub README.md?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319505/how-can-one-display-images-side-by-side-in-a-github-readme-md)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't notice that it's the solution of NEXT theme,so I cannot guarantee the answer is still valid.*

---

**Original answer:**

I also tried to do that before,but failed many times.
Eventually I got the answer in [Official Reference Document](https://theme-next.js.org/docs/tag-plugins/group-pictures).

To be brief,use the format below to insert your imgs.

```
{% gp [number]-[layout] %}
![image description](img's url)
![image description](img's url)
{% endgp %}
```

1. [number] is the amount of your imgs.
2. [layout] is the index of the designed layout. (you can see specific
   layouts in the [Document](https://theme-next.js.org/docs/tag-plugins/group-pictures))

P.S. The Document recommends enabling the "fancybox" plugin,which I did.
So I am not sure whether it would operate normally without enabling fancybox.Please notice!

---

For example,you can get:

"image1 image2" (you mentioned in your question)

by using the code below:

```
{% gp 2-2 %}
![image description](img's url)
![image description](img's url)
{% endgp %}
```

Hope my answer would be helpful! I kown it's really a struggle to grope alone. :)))