# How to align README stats side by side in GitHub

Tags: css, github, readme

I dont know if this is the right place to ask this question but I am really stuck on this part. Basically, I am trying to align my github stats side by side in the readme file.

I added this code in my readme file:

```
![User GitHub Stats](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=user&show_icons=true&theme=radical)
![Top Languages Card](https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=user&theme=radical&layout=compact)
```

How can I make it so that the two cards align side by side? Something like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I tried adding this but it still did not work:

```
<img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=hussaino03&show_icons=true&theme=radical" />
 <img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=hussaino03&theme=radical&layout=compact" />
```

[image]

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
 <img class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=hussaino03&show_icons=true&theme=radical" />
 <img class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=hussaino03&theme=radical&layout=compact" />
</div>
```

Comment: Either `display: flex;` or `float` the elements. Please include your HTML and CSS if you want a relevant solution.

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319505/how-can-one-display-images-side-by-side-in-a-github-readme-md
You might find out your answer there.

Comment: yes, but isnt it different with readme stats?

Comment: I edited my question with what I tried

Comment: I'm almost certain all sorts of styling are filtered out here for reasons of sanitization, so there's probably not a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the CSS I added and changes to your HTML. Simply doing `<img align="center"` is not enough.

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
 <img class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=hussaino03&show_icons=true&theme=radical" />
 <img class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=hussaino03&theme=radical&layout=compact" />
</div>
```

Inspected front-end and changed div styles to those suggested and it worked as expected. [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kC7x.png)

Comment: how would I put the css into the readme file?

Comment: You can use inline styles too. See the adjusted.

Comment: hmm doesnt really work

Comment: see the edited question with my output

Comment: Make sure the new div is nested properly @user2345 add `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: it works in preview for some reason but not in my actual page

Comment: where do I add that?

Comment: in replacement of `display: flex;`?

Comment: @user2345 next to the current inline-styles.

Comment: @user2345 check adjusted.

Comment: nope doesnt work still

Comment: @user2345 then you're going to have to post more of the surrounding code. Sounds like the div is not nested properly.

Comment: what does class = "img" hold though?

Comment: Im gonna post what I have in the question above. See the edited part

Comment: @user2345 all you added was what I gave you... how does that help me? I need to see the pre-existing code around it. Do you have the link to the file?

Comment: there is nothing around it though. That is all I have for the github stats

Comment: @user2345 shoot me a link to the front-end please.

Comment: do you want me to send u the link to my github? That way u can see what the error is?

Comment: https://github.com/hussaino03/hussaino03

Comment: @user2345 check adjusted.

Comment: take a look at the link, I think it will make more sense there

Comment: @user2345 looked at link... edited answer shows that the suggested styles worked as expected. see img attached. I can't help anymore without more code or context. Cause the browser is rendering it properly on my end.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me. Both images are about the same size and on the same line.

```
<div class='container'>
<img style="height: auto; width: 55%;" class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=user&show_icons=true&theme=blue-green" />
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<img style="height: auto; width: 40%;" class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=user&theme=blue-green&langs_count=8&layout=compact" /></div>
</div>
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrLK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in both box sizes annoyed also me. I tried the other proposal here but for some reason it didn't work for me(both in the same size on the same row). So, I did the following that has made them look much better, although they are **not** on the same line

```html
### GitHub Stats
<div><img style="height: auto; width: 40%;" class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=Tsvetoslav88&theme=radical&show_icons=true&include_all_commits=true&hide_border=true" /></div>

### GitHub Languages
<div><img style="height: auto; width: 40%;" class="img" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=Tsvetoslav88&theme=radical&langs_count=8&layout=compact&hide_border=true" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:
Using the dir="auto" (which is used for text alignment) along with max-width 100% you should be able to center whatever you want.

```
<div align="center" dir="auto" <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?username=hussaino03&show_icons=true&theme=radical" />
 <img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=hussaino03&theme=radical&layout=compact" />
</div>
```