# How to add image to readme file in Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am using Stash (which has Git) for my project

I am trying to add some images to my Readme.md file as

```
[picture](http://stash.xxxxxx.com/projects/zzzzz/img/abc.png)
```

but its not working. when i view the readme, all i see is the plain text

```
![picture](http://stash.xxxxxx.com/projects/zzzzz/img/abc.png)
```

please help

EDIT:

Note that stash might be rendering markdowns differently and thats why the conventional solutions to github markdowns might not be applicable. still if somebody know an alternate way of doing this, please let me know.

**EDIT2**

ok, so here is part of the problem

i had the text for the image as part of the text in an ordered list. as you might know, the lists follow an indentation pattern. when i took the text for the image out of the indentation, and added ?raw at then end of the url, the image showed up. Follow up: can i use something similar to the html img tag in order to resize my image ? also is it necessary for me to de-indent the text for referencing the image ? i still can't escape the quotes

Final EDIT:

found the solution for escaping special characters

i had to replace the special characters with their corresponding entity number as per

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stash; are you sure that it renders Markdown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add images to readme.md on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Comment: @Makoto i have been told that it does. i will investigate more

Comment: @user2984552, thanks. yes i have tried that approach as well but it does not work

Comment: It does work. I just tried it in my Stash.

Comment: thanks @user2984552 can you please share the line of code ? also i  i cant seem to be able to escape quotes. i tried using \' but this shows up as 

\�

does stash render markdowns differently ?

Comment: I did not do anything special. It looks exactly like your second link above.

Comment: thanks,
that is strange. i am also quite new to git and stash. could it be related to the version of stash i am using, if there is such a thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add `?raw` to the end of the URL to the image, so Stash will serve up the image, instead of showing you the file image history.

Comment: thanks Larry, but i still get the plain text. should i enclose the url in quotes ?

Comment: What version of stash? It works fine for me in my old install of 2.12.0

Comment: I'd recommend using relative URLs if possible, and you can leave off the ?raw

Comment: The relative link is a good tip. Without ?raw, it shows up as a broken image.

Answer (score 2):

The Stash/BitBucket documentation for images https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/markdown-syntax-guide-776639995.html#Markdownsyntaxguide-Images provides markdown syntax to just link images "first class".  Assuming my README.md is at the root of my project,

```
![Sequence Diagram](./doc/fields_seq_diagram.png)
```

...works like a champ on a directory structure like

```
tcc-rkuhar:shaggy robert.kuhar$ tree --charset=ascii
.
|-- README.md
|-- doc
|   |-- fields_seq_diagram.png
|   `-- fields_seq_diagram.txt
|-- project.clj
```

Answer (score 1):

1. One way is to use the markdown syntax of adding an image. This is possible because this file is a markdown file.
   The syntax looks like:

   ![Alt text](image link):
2. You can simply drag and drop Images