# GitHub README.md not displaying web-linked URL images

Tags: image, url, github, markdown

I've researched several other SO questions about placing images into markdown documents on GitHub. Most often they only talk about relative linking to image files contained in the project repo, or hosted in some GitHub user content location, and needing "raw" links, etc.

I'm instead trying to display images in README.md that are just simple web URL links to images at a website (my company's website, in fact). This is for an enterprise hosted GitHub repo and a project that needs to display the result of certain image URLs at the site.

Here's a pared down version of what I am doing:

```
# image project
Prototype of some image project

![test](http://samplesite.com/somesample.jpg)

<img src="http://samplesite.com/somesample.jpg" width="300"/>
```

where I can verify by putting the real image path for `http://samplesite.com/somesample.jpg` into my browser that it's a correct and functioning URL that displays the desired image.

Yet, when I commit this and push to the remote branch, then ensure I am looking at the correct branch on the GitHub website (and the README.md source code correctly shows these image entries) -- it does not display any images. It's as if these items aren't even in the markdown source at all. There's not even any response if I hover or mouse over the places where the images should be showing up.

I've tried using only one or the other of the two examples (e.g. only the markdown syntax or only the HTML syntax).

Why don't these images display when the markdown file is rendered at the project repo site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14494775/7063373 - please find if this  is helpful

Comment: @satya-j Unfortunately it's not helpful. I already read that link before posting this. It suggests that just using basic markdown image syntax for a web URL should "just work" but it fails to work. That post is also mostly about relative paths to an image within the repository, I don't think any of the people involved in that answer tried it with a web URL, they just assumed that since that's what's documented, then it should work (but it doesn't seem to).

Comment: Looks like http is not supported. Only https