# Add images to README.org files in Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab, org-mode, readme

A method to add images to markdown files in Github is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github). However, I would like to add images to `*.org` files in Gitlab (both Github and Gitlab support `README.org` files, so the solution should be equal for both). I've tried:

```
[[file:./path/to/file.svg]]
[[sometext][file:./path/to/file.svg]]]
[[file:./path/to/file.svg]][sometext]]
```

Markdown's format doesn't work either:

```
![alt text](./path/to/file.svg)
```

A now removed answer suggested using

```
![][1]

[1]: ./path/tofile
```

which doesn't work either.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insetting `html` works for both Gitlab and Github.

```
#+html: <p align="center"><img src="path/to/file" /></p>
```

Comment: Although disappointing, this seems to be the only solution if you want the image to be displayed correctly, as of now. Hopefully support for `#+attr_html` will appear in GitLab and GitHub.
I had to add `width=700` inside the img tag, to correct the display.

Answer (score 0):

```
#+caption: <img description> (optional)
#+attr_html: :width 50 px
#+attr_html: :height 50 px
[[<path to image>]]
```

For more check the [orgmode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-HTML-export.html#Images-in-HTML-export).

Comment: Your answer seemed promising, but it didn't work on my GitLab instance - image was not resized. Did you try it in a Git context?

Comment: @kotchwane as of that answer, after trying it for a long time, I gave up and assumed that GitLab engine rendering handles image dimensions itself and completely ignores such attributes.

Comment: There seems to be an issue opened on this subject for GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30487).
So it might work one day - but as of now, it doesn't