# Add Image to GitHub Readme.md from Google Drive

Tags: github, google-drive-api, github-flavored-markdown

I have the image in Drive, How could it be added to the Readme.md so as to display the image in readme.
I had tried with the shared link, but it isn't working.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/14494775/5517435

Comment: But, neither of them seems working in the case of Google Drive Images since the absolute URLs aren't available.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

For example, I have `a.jpg` on the google drive.

1. Right click the image and click `Share...`
2. Click `Advanced` and change the `Who can access` option to `Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet`
3. Copy the `link to share` and you will have something like

   > https://drive.google.com/file/d/**<FILE_ID>**/view?usp=sharing
4. Copy the <FILE_ID>  to make a link like this:

   > https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=**<FILE_ID>**
5. Insert image in Markdown as ususal using the link from step 4. 
    For example: 
   `![image](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILE_ID>)`

Example: I have this octocat image in google, and its file id is `1913oZeBZPBNiUuk8gu3ZSbLBA2l_VQtG`. You can try `![image](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1913oZeBZPBNiUuk8gu3ZSbLBA2l_VQtG)` in your markdown file or even in this answer.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works on a desktop, but not on iOS unfortunately, don't know why but even Octocat image from the response is not visible on iOS. Does anybody has a solution?

Comment: great, works with gifs too. ![Alt Text](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17QCIuE6bUQXMz5tZ_TvHXkiNs7Uohihk)

Comment: It works with your ID but not with my IDs. I have try with different link it simple do not work

Answer (score 10):

## How to insert an Image in a github-flavoured markdown format and be able to adjust its size

1. Upload the image `image.jpg` to your Google Drive
2. Click the `get link` button at the top right corner

[image: Get Link]

3. Change the permission type to `Anyone with the link`

[image]

4. Copy (to clipboard) only the file ID `<FILEID>` from the full link as shown (highlighted in blue) and click `Done`. At the time of writing the shareable link takes the form:

> [https://drive.google.com/file/d/`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/%60)`/view?usp=sharing

[image]

5. Insert Image in markdown using the copied file id `<FILEID>` and anchor tag as shown:

`<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILEID>"><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILEID>" style="width: 650px; max-width: 100%; height: auto" title="Click to enlarge picture" />`

Note that the brackets '<' and '>' are not to be present with the file ID.
The size of the image can be adjusted in the style attribute by adjusting the width and the height as needed. Clicking the rendered image will open it to its original size

Comment: Followed these steps, still not working for me. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The working format after Google changed the URL format. You need to get the image URL by getting the link after setting 'Anyone with the link' option.

`![Example Image](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1A1cNS98neP17g3jkpcbDGlrRik1QNNbm)`

You need to provide the image id you're trying to embed as in the template format below.

`![Example Image](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<YOUR_IMAGE_ID>)`

Answer (score 1):

If you could not access any solution you can kind of use brute force:

1. Open developer console - use Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux).
2. Click Ctrl + Shift + C to access the hover effect and click over the image.
3. The url of the image will appear, click to open into another screen or copy the link
   [image]
4. Add the link to your .md file: `![Alt text](<the link of the image>)`