# Image not embedded into a md file in GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I am trying to enrich my repository with screenshots of my query outputs.

What I was planning was to add this images in a Readme.md file associated with each directory.

I followed all the approaches given in this questions without sucess (some of the answers are rather old and github may have change):

[Add images to README.md on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14494747/1773841)

And the one which gave me better results was this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvPOUdz5PL4

So what I did was to create an issue, and added the link like this:

```
![pcaex1](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20033386/46548188-5b4f8380-c8df-11e8-8ba9-5f5322e4cbb5.jpg)
```

However this is the result:

[image]

I can only see the link. And I need to press that link to see the image itself. But is is not embedded.

Do you know if this feature was removed from GIT/md or if there is a new better approach.

Edit: Probably the problem is how I am saving this images in GitHub, since when I try to access them I get:
[image]

Is there any format/size/dimension restriction in github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `pcaEx1.jpg` file in the same folder as your `README.md`, just use:

```
![](pcaEx1.jpg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am starting to believe the problem is when I upload the image to github is not possible to visualize. I updated my question with a screenshot of how it looks like when I try to access a recently uploaded image. Do you know if there is any restriction when uploading the images in github?

Comment: can you post a link to that github repo? can you open the image directly in a browser?

Comment: This is the link to the image, and I am not table to see it. Just what I posted: https://github.com/ignacio-alorre/SparkML/blob/master/PCA/pcaEx2.png

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and Firefox on macOS. So probably it's your browser :-)

Comment: Chrome 69, but if you have a somewhat current browser, then it might be your firewall, adblocker, or something like that..