# github markdown no longer displays images

Tags: github

A month or 2 ago I wrote a markdown file for my github page and it contained png files.
Today I was looking ad the markdown file on github and all images were removed. If I click on one I get the message: The image "link to image" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

This is the link as the git hub page gives me
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bask185/State-Machine-Scripts/master/images/handleWheel.png

And this is how I try to display the file in the markdown file.
 exclamation mark [handleWheel ] (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bask185/State-Machine-Scripts/master/images/handleWheel.png)

It worked once so I did something right once. Did github changed or did I do something wrong?
Can I salvage my images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the images were linked to a relative path in your repository. You earlier had an `images/` directory with the images that were shown in the markdown file, but this was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/bask185/State-Machine-Scripts/commit/7f5f3dea386817e32131f10511d652724c18b865).

If you browse the repository at the previous commit, you can [see the images](https://github.com/bask185/State-Machine-Scripts/tree/1953c0564d74ce29c28683c27bc7a0b1018038e6/images). The image corresponding to the link in your question, for example, is [here](https://github.com/bask185/State-Machine-Scripts/blob/1953c0564d74ce29c28683c27bc7a0b1018038e6/images/handleWheel.png).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14494747/5987698) discusses various ways to add images to Markdown files in GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. I see I must be more carefull with git. When searchin the problem online I happened to came across that same thread. I noticed that people have many different ideas about adding images