# How to add a background image to Github README.md

Tags: github

Is it possible to put a background image to Github repository `README.md`? There is this [highly cited question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github) with many answers. However, I could not find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those answers are about including pictures in a markdown file, as rendered by GitHub in [GFM (GitHub Flavored Markdown)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#images)

There is no support for background image in that case.

Only [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) would be able to render those files as HTML, with possibly background images, as part of a static website generator.