# Add images on readme page

Tags: github, readme

Recently I found out about the "secret" readme page on Github and I added some information including a few images.

The problem I face is that my images won't appear.

[image]

And this is the root.

[image]

And lastly my markup for the images

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add images to README.md on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
 [![Twitter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/username/master/images/twitter.png)](Twitter link here)
```

Replace username/username with your actual username or user/repo for a repository readme, and add your Twitter link where indicated.

Same thing for other images, this way when users click on the image, they will directed to your twitter link