# Changing README.md image display conditional to GitHub light-mode / dark-mode

Tags: github, readme

Is it possible to change README.md image display in GitHub that is conditional to GitHub's dark-mode and light-mode? Perhaps a simple conditional I can put in my README.md.

Comment: No solution yet, but anyone landing here in the future may want to check up on this thread https://github.community/t/support-theme-context-for-images-in-light-vs-dark-mode/147981

Comment: They just announced the `picture` (with `source` having the `media` query on `prefers-color-scheme`), the "old" https://github.community is being phased down it seems. You can now go to https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/16910

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## ⚠️ UPDATE - 22-6-2022

> **The old method** of specifying images based on the theme, by using a fragment appended to the URL (#gh-dark-mode-only or #gh-light-mode-only), **is deprecated and will be removed ...** [[source]](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to)

## ✨ NEW METHOD

```markdown
<picture>
  <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" srcset="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/w.png">
  <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" srcset="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/b.png">
  <img alt="Shows a black logo in light color mode and a white one in dark color mode." src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25423296/163456779-a8556205-d0a5-45e2-ac17-42d089e3c3f8.png">
</picture>
```

[^ SOURCE](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to) | [DEMONSTRATION](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/tree/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149) | [MORE INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413712/changing-readme-md-image-display-conditional-to-github-light-mode-dark-mode/70200610#comment127751501_65413712)

## ⚠️ OLD METHOD

**It is now possible** to conditionally specify what image to be displayed based on the theme, by using the below keywords at the end of the desired light\dark-themed image-link.

| **`#gh-dark-mode-only`** | **`#gh-light-mode-only`** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: GitHub-Mark-Light] | [image: GitHub-Mark-Dark] |

#### ^ [examples](https://github.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/tree/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149) of use :

```html
<p align="center">
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/b.png#gh-light-mode-only" height="120" width="120"/>
    <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/w.png#gh-dark-mode-only" height="120" width="120"/>
</p>
```

```markdown
![GitHub-Mark-Light](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/b.png#gh-light-mode-only)
![GitHub-Mark-Dark ](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GiorgosXou/Random-stuff/main/Programming/StackOverflow/Answers/70200610_11465149/w.png#gh-dark-mode-only)
```

**Make sure the images are stored in github else they won't display dynamically based on the theme**. For more informations click [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to) and [here](https://github.community/t/support-theme-context-for-images-in-light-vs-dark-mode/147981/86)

Comment: Thank god there's a new way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can now specify whether to display images for light or dark themes in Markdown, using the HTML `<picture>` element in combination with the `prefers-color-scheme` media feature.

For example:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" srcset="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25423296/163456776-7f95b81a-f1ed-45f7-b7ab-8fa810d529fa.png">
  <img alt="Shows an illustrated sun in light color mode and a moon with stars in dark color mode." src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25423296/163456779-a8556205-d0a5-45e2-ac17-42d089e3c3f8.png">
</picture>
```

Reference: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-19-specify-theme-context-for-images-in-markdown-beta/

Answer (score 0):

To go with Giorgos "NEW METHOD" answer, here's what works for me for SVGs.

1. Put the .svg in its own file; and use `<style>` to describe the default light colors, and the alternate dark colors, for the elements of the svg, e.g. `<g>` in this example.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 182 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    g { fill: black; }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      g { fill: white; }
    }
  </style>

  <g stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd">
     ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

2. In the README.md, link the .svg like you'd link an image

```
![logo](docs/logo.svg)
```

NOTE: turns out this isn't working on desktop Safari, mobile Safari, and all other iOS browsers (which use mobile Safari). Hopefully I find a technique that does work.