# Publishing images to be included in README.md on NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

In [this project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator) the `README.md` displays the `logo/pnglogo.png` logo at the top of the `README.md` file.

We'd like the same logo to display on NPM.  So we copy it into the `dist/fs-validator` directory where the publish files are located.  This is the npm script (From `package.json`):

```
"p": "cp README.md ./projects/fs-validator/ && npm run bp && npm run b && cp -r logo ./dist/fs-validator/ && cd dist/fs-validator/ && npm publish",
```

If I understand correctly, this should publish the logo directory along with the other files.  However the logo is not showing up at the top of the `README.md` within NPM. How can I fix that?

I moved the logo to the root of the repository and changed the `README.md` to include it like this:

```
![Validator](pnglogo.png)
```

As that works for publishing with this repository:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice

However I'm still not getting any success.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out.  The `package.json` that I was publishing did not have the Github repository fields included.

```json
{
  "name": "@fireflysemantics/validator",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@fireflysemantics/is": "*",
    "@fireflysemantics/validatorts": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Apparently these are needed in order for NPM to know where the image is located.

I changed `package.json` to incoulde the repository data so that it now looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@fireflysemantics/validator",
  "version": "0.0.11",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Validation",
    "Javascript",
    "Typescript",
    "Angular Package Format"
  ],
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@fireflysemantics/is": "*",
    "@fireflysemantics/validatorts": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

And now the logo shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by hosting the image in something like amazon s3 and then give url instead of related path