# Rendering svg images in Jupyter notebook markdown on GitHub

Tags: github, svg, jupyter-notebook, markdown

The markdown code below can be rendered in Jupyter notebook locally in my browser, but it doesn't reader on GitHub (instead shown as broken image icons)

```markdown
<img src="img/plot1_m_over_n=5.svg" width="500"> <img src="img/plot2_m_over_n=10.svg" width="500">
```

There's a lot of math so I used Jupyter notebook (LaTeX) for the readme (no code cells, just lots of markdown cells), and I know there is a python solution [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb) (In [8]), but I don't want to show the python code. I just want the SVGs to be rendered! Plus it can't resize the svg. How can I adjust the markdown code above so that it can be rendered on GitHub?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to change those URLs to the raw links, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14494775/354577

Comment: @Chris Oh gosh, I just found that it can render correctly in a public repo, but not in a private one (which I tested before).

Comment: @Chris And I believe replacing them with explicit URLs should solve the not rendering problem in a private repo ; )

Comment: I'm surprised that this makes any difference for public vs. private repositories. As long as you're logged in and have access to the repo, the links should work.