# Difficulty in uploading images on GitHub

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm finding it difficult to upload an image to my GitHub readme page and repository. I have tried the formats I saw on YouTube, but none of them worked.

I tried using []Alt and () image link. Also I tried uploading the image by dragging the screenshot in to the GitHub readme page or repository.

Lastly, I tried uploading the image on the issue page and copy the image address to the intended location but it didn't work. It kept on showing cracked image

I'm trying to find a way to upload the images without showing cracked image.

Comment: You may also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/how-to-add-images-to-readme-md-on-github/14494775#14494775

Comment: Please edit the question to show actual examples. The example you left under the answer is critical to understand your actual problem, so it belongs in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In general GitHubs `README.md` uses markdown. To include images you can use these syntaxes:

```
Here's our logo (hover to see the title text):

Inline-style: 
![alt text](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "Logo Title Text 1")

Reference-style: 
![alt text][logo]

[logo]: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "Logo Title Text 2"
```

The link in the `()` can be relative, like in the `./docs/my-img.png` or absolut via a URL like `https://i.imgur.com/Ozgwrq2.jpeg`

See [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) for a complete markdown cheatsheet

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @hegerdes but I have tried the format but it's not working

Comment: Did you use a relative or absolute url. And did you upload your image in the repo? Please share what you used

Comment: I used relative and absolute url but none of them worked. I uploaded the image and still it's showing cracked image. Below is the link;
![Screenshot 2024-03-12 160938](https://github.com/Julian's portfolio/Tata-Virtual-Internship-with-forage/assets/118804668/b44653c3-14f3-4da6-8ebf-d8e9544

Comment: The quotes and spaces in the URL are likely the problem. First bit of advice, change the name of your GitHub space to remove the space and apostrophe. I'm surprised they work at all, but even if they do you'll have no end of troubles such as you're getting here. You'll have to figure out how to encode them everywhere you use them.

Comment: You might be able to get them working here by replacing them by their % encoding, like your browser navigation bar shows when you load the site.

Comment: Oh, I'm getting a 404 with https://github.com/Julian's%20portfolio/ . The question may also be about whether you can link to an image within a private repo in its readme, and see it. Probably yes, because you would have to be logged in to see the readme in the first place, but it's worth checking.

Comment: OP seems to ne new to markdown. So it es best to learn the basics. Currently it is hard to help OP without proper examples and missing/broken links from his side. @joanis. Including private pictures on GitHub is not a problem since the browser inherits the aktive user session for requesting the picture.

Comment: @joanis. I will try it and see if it'll work. Thank you

Comment: @joanis I removed the apostrophe and replaced it with % and still it didn't work. I feel like I need to see someone that's very good with GitHub one on one