# Display GitHub README screenshot stored in a different branch, both on GitHub and locally

Tags: git, github, screenshot, git-branch, readme

**Update:** This is the [GitHub test repository](https://github.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch) for this question.

I'm storing a screenshot (`screenshot.png`) in a separate Git branch (`assets`), to be used in a README.md file (on the `master` branch).

To see the image on GitHub, I have to link to:

```
/../assets/screenshot.png
```

or

```
../assets/screenshot.png
```

However, this does not work when viewing the README file locally, the image is not displayed (such as when using the Markdown preview feature in VS Code or Atom).

I have even used the *git worktree* feature, to check out the *assets* branch in the *assets* subdirectory:

```
git worktree add -B assets assets origin/assets
```

so the directory structure is something like this:

```
.git
assets
assets/screenshot.png
README.md
```

This means that, in order to view the image locally in the README file, I have to link to

```
/assets/screenshot.png
```

or

```
assets/screenshot.png
```

How can I reconcile the two "worlds"?

Is there a way to link to the screenshot so it's always displayed, "whether I view the documentation on GitHub itself, or locally, using a different markup renderer"[*](https://blog.github.com/2013-01-31-relative-links-in-markup-files/)?

Comment: If you're checking out branch X, any files *only* on branch Y aren't expected to be available. They're in the repository, just not in your working folder. The reason this works on GitHub seems to be a fluke related to how GitHub stores and processes repositories. In short, I wouldn't expect this to work *at all*.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen For example with Visual Studio Code, with the _Open preview to the side_ (Markdown preview) option.

Comment: The file GitHub is serving as your readme file is through this url - `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch/master/README.md` - and as you can see the branch name is part of that url, master. If you remove the filename and append your asset link you get - `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch/master/../assets/screenshot.png` which will work, but that's just related to how GitHub serves raw copies of your files. Don't expect this to work anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible and you shouldn't expect it to.

You should make the assets folder a part of your main branch, or you should separate the two into different repositories, or something along those lines.

There is a good reason why GitHub serves this screenshot but that "good reason" is just a technical reason related to how GitHub serves content from your repository.

Let's look at the URL to your screenshot, as used in the served HTML from your main repository page:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch/assets/screenshot.png
```

As you can see, the name of the branch with the image is part of the URL. Let's try to hack the URL back to your README:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch/master/README.md
```

If you try this URL you will see that it shows your README file.

So the issue here is that your "hack" to get to the screenshot, from another branch, is that you get this URL:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch/master/../assets/screenshot.png
```

This resolves to the exact same URL as the first one i posted here and that is why you see the image.

**However**, if you check out branch X then you shouldn't expect any content from branch Y to be present in your working folder. It "works" on GitHub because of the way they serve content from your branches but it won't, and **shouldn't** work locally, except if you start checking out multiple branches using worktrees.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using the worktree feature, as mentioned in the question, so I have the `screenshot.png` file from the `assets` branch in the working folder, as `assets/screenshot.png`. The problem is that locally the assets folder is one level down the root of my working folder, and on GitHub it seems to be one level up, because of how GitHub relative links work with branches.

Comment: Yes, and the root cause is that you're expecting behavior which is not supported. It is a "fluke" that it works on GitHub, it will not necessarily work anywhere else **because you shouldn't expect it to**. You need to find another way to host your assets if you absolutely don't want them in your master branch.

Comment: I way trying to find a way to host screenshots (not essential binary images) for README files, without polluting the `master` branch / working folder, the Git history, or growing the size of the repository. With a separate `assets` branch, with or without `git worktree`, and using `git commit --amend`, together with `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` and `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`, I could keep only the latest version of the screenshots, without any history.

Comment: How about simply switching to using the full URL through GitHub in your README.md file?

Comment: Thank you. Absolute _https://raw.githubusercontent.com_ urls already work with the `assets` branch way from my question: the README screenshot loads both locally and on GitHub. (Locally with some minor _Allow insecure content_ tweaks in the Markdown preview.) I have updated the [test repository](https://github.com/devliber/ReadmeScreenshotBranch) to reflect this. However, my desire was to use portable, relative URLs, that make it easy to move the repository from GitHub (if needed), that load images offline, etc.

Comment: Also, when using the full `raw.githubusercontent.com` URL through GitHub, what happens if GitHub decides to change the URL scheme / raw file path?

Comment: It will probably stop working, but just to clarify, you are still asking how to do something which is not really supposed to work. You're doing a hack, nobody promises this will keep on working. There is no solid, documented, supported, way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with using an external service, you can use [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) to display the image on a different branch.

For example, if you had two branches `main` and `assets` under `username/repo`, you could link an image under the `assets` branch likewise:

```
# README.md

![Image from another branch](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/username/repo@assets/screenshot.png)
```

However, this will not work locally.