# Is there any harm in uploading an Image on Github server by using the following hack?

Tags: github

1. Drop image inside issues comment section
2. Use the generated markdown wherever you want

I use this hack to upload screenshots of my android application.
By harm I imply, will my image be removed ever ?

Learnt this hack from Christian Specht's answer to this question.
[Official image host for GitHub projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360714/official-image-host-for-github-projects)

Comment: So you are using GitHub as a content host by hot-linking the image in your android application?

Comment: No, I am uploading screenshot of my android application by hot-linking to be uploaded in README.md