# Store an uploaded image to Github using NodeJS and Github API

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, vue.js

Been Struggling to try to push an Image to my repo on Github using NodeJS and Github API, I've covered the part of creating the SHA,Commit Tree and everything, the only thing left is to pass the image to the API and saving it as an actual Image (e.g test.png)

What I did so far is retrieving the image like below:

`reader.onload = (e) => {
    image = reader.result.split(',')[1]
}`

Then sending it to the NodeJS server to get Sent to Github, but it's only stored as test.jpg but the content is not an actual Image but just :

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAAqA.....`

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay solved it! the only thing that I had to add is to actually convert the **base64** content to Binary using this:

`var data = Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64');`

And then sending this data to a commit which worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this blog post](https://www.labnol.org/internet/free-file-hosting-github/29092/), you might have to add `?raw=true` to the end of the src url. Alternately, I found a hack on a [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959426).