# How to display an animated GIF in a github README file?

Tags: github

this question may sound silly but if I understood correctly Github is unable to display MP4 video files in a README.md, however it is possible to display an animated GIF. Am I right? I was wondering where is the best practice to store that animated GIF file, in the repository itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add a gif to a Markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341808/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-gif-to-a-markdown-file)

Answer (score 13):

GitHub supports GIFs in READMEs. Here's an example, using Markdown, that I tested on a GitHub repository.

```
![hippo](https://media3.giphy.com/media/aUovxH8Vf9qDu/giphy.gif)
```

GIFs inside the repo can be used, too. This link format seems stable:

```
![til](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hashrocket/hr-til/master/app/assets/images/banner.png)
```

Relative paths work too:

```
![til](./app/assets/images/banner.png)
```

I think a best practice would be to host the GIF online using a service like Giphy. If it's stored in the repo, anyone who clones that repo will have to download the GIF onto their machine. Unless it's also integral to the application, you might let an external service handle the hosting.

Comment: Just a side note: the GIF can also be hosted inside the repository. In this case, it needs to be accessed using a relative path or `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<User>/<Repository>/<branch>/<path/to/gif>`. The problem is that this would be a binary file in a github repo...

Comment: One last thing: it seems that github also supports relative paths to images (e.g. `./animation.gif`) in markdown files...

Comment: @dan1st I tested that too and it worked; answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is one easy way. Upload your gif to the repo then copy the address of your gif. For example, I uploaded a gif named me.gif. Here is the link.

```
https://github.com/Daisyliu6/Daisyliu6/blob/master/me.gif
```

then just put in the README.md

```
![me](https://github.com/Daisyliu6/Daisyliu6/blob/master/me.gif)
```

Comment: Finally found a comment that helps! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

Relative path:

```
<img src="./assets/image.gif"/>
```

or image from the internet

```
 <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/aUovxH8Vf9qDu/giphy.gif
"/>
```

Another advantage is that you can specify your own width and height:

```
<img src="./assets/image.gif" width="50%" height="50%"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your gif is inside the repository you can do this

```
![alternative text](path to your gif)
```

for example you have the gif in the root  directory then

```
![any alternative text you want ](./gifname.gif)
```