# Create a link to the header of another page in Github

Tags: github, markdown

Does anyone know how to create a link to the header of a different wiki page?

I know if I have a header `##Header name` that I can link to it on that page by using `(#header-name)` as my link, but I want to link to that header from a different page. Is this possible?

ie. I want to have a table of contents that can link to the sub-sections of each wiki page as well as to the page itself.

Edit: I mean a way besides just using the url link
`http://github.com/project/wiki/Wiki-Page#header-name`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT 1**: So totally wrong about before, I just read up a bit more. So we have this new support as well inside of GitHub Wikis! (Relatively new.)

You can also do something like this:

```
[[ Link text | page_title#header_title ]]
```

This might work a lot better for you! TIL because of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8972756/4162814). You can see me do this with the Prerequisite link and you can see my other links work the other way. Time for me to do some updates!

---

**EDIT 1**: Still useful but definitely **NOT THE ONLY WAY**.

So I answered a question about this before, you **should** avoid absolute links on [GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203580/images-in-markdown-files-in-github-enterprise/36363835#36363835) (i.e. https://github.com/user/repo_name/...)

However, a good way (and kind of the only way inside of Wikis **EDIT 1**: TOTALLY NOT TRUE TO BEING THE ONLY WAY) of doing what you need can be seen like this:

```
[Header link](/user/repository_name/wiki/page_name#title).
```

This is kind of the linking unfortunately that the Wiki would support. This will change your directory page based off of GitHub. You can see that it would be

```
https://github.com/(the linkage you want to hit)
```

I have actually began doing something like this in a Wiki I work on [here](https://github.com/chardane/ClarifaiRuby/wiki/Home). Inside of my Sidebar, you can see I have a Getting Started Page, and then a subsection into it is a Prerequisite heading and it will properly lead people to where they need to go. You would be able to perform this same thing on any page. It is a tad verbose, but worth it as you can easily change things around if need be. This is also case-sensitive since it will change their location so be sure that in your linkage, the page is the proper case and your heading is all lowercase.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Only `[Header link](/user/repository_name/wiki/page_name#title)` worked for me, but note that the url is relative if you don't use a preceding slash.

Answer (score 4):

You can link to the header by simply assigning an id to header. e.g you've "Extension" header in a page called Abc.
 `# <a id="extension"></a> Extensions`
You have another page "Call center" and you want to go to extension in abc , you can use reference linking of markdown i.e "The [extensions][1] are handled by agents"
`[1]: url-of-abc/#extension`

Answer (score 0):

I tested Maxwell's *"good way"* to [link to the header](https://github.com/marmot7/website/wiki) of another page in Github in **Edit 1** on  and it works perfectly.

```
#[crux-ports Installation](/user/crux-ports/blob/master/README.md#installation)
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, it will just try to go to that header on the current page.

Comment: Couldn't throw some HTML in there? `<a href="example-wiki-url#anchor">Link Text</a>`

My understanding is you can put HTML anywhere in a Markdown document.

Answer (score 0):

markdown generate slug for the heading and convert it to id, example

```markdown
# [ topic ][ color ]
```

will be converted to

```html
<h1 id="topic--color" data-line="643" class="code-line">[ topic ][ color ]</h1>
```

Thus, to link it you can write it as `[color](#topic--color)`.

If the destination anchor is on another page (assume filename `css.md`) with path relative to current markdown page, then you can write it as `[color](css.md#topic--color)`

Attach the slugify function from vscode

```js
// excerpt from https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/blob/908d7ba5465a203e4299f346c179211d992ef468/src/util/slugify.ts

const str = '# [ topic ][ color ]';

const slug = encodeURI(
            str.trim()
                .replace(/\s+/g, "-") // Replace whitespace with -
                .replace(/[\]\[\!\'\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\\\^\_\{\|\}\~\`。，、；：？！…—·ˉ¨‘’“”々～‖∶＂＇｀｜〃〔〕〈〉《》「」『』．〖〗【】（）［］｛｝]/g, "") // Remove known punctuators
                .replace(/^\-+/, "") // Remove leading -
                .replace(/\-+$/, "") // Remove trailing -
        );
        
 console.log(slug) // "topic--color"
```