# How can I embed a YouTube video on GitHub wiki pages?

Tags: video, github, youtube, embed, markdown

I am fairly new to markup (though it's extremely easy to pickup). I am working on a package and am trying to get the wiki pages looking nice as a help manual. I can insert a YouTube video link into the wiki page pretty easily but how do I embed a YouTube video. I know this may not be possible.

I have read you can use HTML tags so I tried embedding with HTML per this [link](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-youtube.html) as follows:

```html
<object width="425" height="350">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/user/wwwLoveWatercom?v=BTRN1YETpyg" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/user/wwwLoveWatercom?v=BTRN1YETpyg"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350" />
</object>
```

And saved the page but nothing happened.

1. Is it possible to embed a YouTube video on GitHub wiki pages?
2. If so how?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279611/how-to-embed-a-video-into-github-readme-md?rq=1

Answer (score 756, accepted):

It's not possible to embed videos directly, but you can put an image which links to a YouTube video:

```
[![IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE](https://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE)
```

- For more information about Markdown look at [this Markdown cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#youtube-videos) on GitHub.
- For more information about Youtube image links [look this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api).

Comment: The iframe does not work for wiki pages, only this solution currently works.

Comment: Modifying your answer as [Mahmoud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260229/mahmoud) suggested on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862696/7123660) may make sense to improve the quality of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 415):

## Complete Example

> Expanding on *@MGA*'s Answer

While it's not possible to *embed* a video in Markdown you can "fake it" by including a valid linked image in your markup file, using this format:

`[![IMAGE ALT TEXT](http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE "Video Title")`

### Explanation of the Markdown

If this markup snippet looks complicated, break it down into two parts:

an image
`![image alt text](https://example.com/link-to-image)`
wrapped in a link
`[link text](https://example.com/my-link "link title")`

### Example using Valid Markdown and YouTube Thumbnail:

[image: Everything Is AWESOME]

We are sourcing the thumbnail image directly from YouTube and linking to the actual video, so when the person clicks the image/thumbnail they will be taken to the video.

### Code:

`[![Everything Is AWESOME](https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y "Everything Is AWESOME")`

***OR*** If you want to give readers a visual cue that the image/thumbnail is actually a *playable* video, take your own screenshot of the video in YouTube and use that as the thumbnail instead.

### Example using Screenshot with Video Controls as Visual Cue:

[image: Everything Is AWESOME]

### Code:

`[![Everything Is AWESOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ceS.png)](https://youtu.be/StTqXEQ2l-Y?t=35s "Everything Is AWESOME")`

### ***Clear* Advantages**

While this requires a couple of extra steps (**a**) *taking the screenshot* of the video and (**b**) *uploading it* so you can use the image as your thumbnail it does have **3 *clear* advantages**:

1. The person reading your markdown (or resulting html page) has a **visual cue** telling them they can watch the video (*video controls encourage clicking*)
2. You can chose a **specific frame** in the video to use as the thumbnail (thus making your content **more engaging**)
3. You can **link to a specific time** in the video from which play will start when the linked-image is clicked. (in our case from 35 seconds)

Taking and uploading a screenshot takes a few seconds but has a big payoff.

## Works Everywhere!

Since this is standard markdown, it works everywhere. try it on GitHub, Reddit, Ghost, and  here on Stack Overflow.

## Vimeo

This approach also works with Vimeo videos

### Example

[image: Little red riding hood]

### Code

```
[![Little red riding hood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRlR.png)](https://vimeo.com/3514904 "Little red riding hood - Click to Watch!")
```

## Notes:

- How to take screenshot: http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ (all platforms)
- Upload Thumbnail Image: Once you've taken your screenshot you can drag-and-drop it into [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3xiA.jpg) to upload and immediately use it as your thumbnail
- YouTube thumbnail info: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: I recently found that I had to omit the http / https URL scheme from the URL to get this to work, i.e. `[![Everything Is AWESOME](//img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/0.jpg)](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y "Everything Is AWESOME")`

Comment: @StephenQuan which markdown parser/platform were you using? we use the code *with* the `http` or `https` on GitHub e.g: https://github.com/dwyl/remote-working where the video image and link work...

Comment: You can switch between the image quality of the thumbnail by replacing the `0.jpg` with `hqdefault.jpg` or `maxresdefault.jpg`.

https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/0.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/hqdefault.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 60):

Markdown does not *officially* support video embeddings but you can embed raw HTML in it. I tested out with **GitHub Pages** and it works flawlessly.

1. Go to the Video page on YouTube and click on the Share Button
2. Choose Embed
3. Copy and Paste the HTML snippet in your markdown

The snippet looks like:

```html
    <iframe width="560" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MUQfKFzIOeU" 
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

PS: You can check out the [live preview here](https://daksh.github.io/Learning-Git-and-GitHub/)

Comment: This iframe strategy looked promising. However, it does not work in [my repo's](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) READ.md file.

Comment: This may not work on README.md's, but it definitely works in github pages.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work inside Github Readme.md, with Vimeo videos at the moment.

Comment: I tried this in a PR comment and it also is not supported there either.

Comment: Does not work on GitHub Wiki. Gollum does not support that.

Comment: This is not Github Wiki Pages, which is what OP is talking about. Github Pages is HTML without restrictions, so it's obvious it supports iframe tags

Answer (score 18):

If you like HTML tags more than markdown + center alignment:

```html
<div align="center">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg" alt="IMAGE ALT TEXT"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

Adding a link with the thumbnail, originally used by YouTube is a solution, that works.
The thumbnail, used by YouTube is accessible the following way:

- if the official video link is:

  - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yLzZikS15k`
- then the thumbnail is:

  - `https://img.youtube.com/vi/5yLzZikS15k/0.jpg`

Following this logic, the code below produces flawless results:

```html
<div align="left">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yLzZikS15k">
         <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/5yLzZikS15k/0.jpg" style="width:100%;">
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Very useful in GitHub Wiki, because the drag and drop of mp4 files does not create a video thumbnail (as of today)

Comment: This does not display the "play" button so it looks static and viewer doesn't know it's clickable/playable.

Answer (score 8):

Center align Video with Thumbnail and Link:

```
<div align="center">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y">
     <img 
      src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/0.jpg" 
      alt="Everything Is AWESOME" 
      style="width:100%;">
      </a>
    </div>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer because it is easy to automate! To that end, the template for that image link is `https://img.youtube.com/vi/ID_OF_VIDEO/0.jpg` and the API for forming image links is explained in detail in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/55478

Answer (score 7):

### October 2022 Update

Why work so hard?

github.com allows dragging / dropping images & videos into Issues and PRs.

If you edit your `README.md` on github.com and drag/drop an MP4 into the page, you get an embedded video player with audio (which you do not get with a GIF).

There is a size limit... I think it's 100 MB for assets uploaded this way.

### Huge Advantages

- The MP4 is not in the `.git` repo so does not impact clone speed or local repo size
- No other services involved (no YouTube, no 3rd part apps)
- Audio (GIFs are great... but there is a reason we don't go to silent movies today)

### Demo Time

https://github.com/huntharo/video-test

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as a trick I have encountered this issue by converting my screen recorded video into a gif using an online converter then I have added it to my markdown like so:

```
## Quick Overview of the project

![Functional Programming with Javascript using NASA API](./functionJsWithNasaAPI.gif)
```

The result was like this in the image below

Check [this repo](https://github.com/DinaTaklit/Mars-Dashbord-functional-programming-Intermediate-JavaScript-Nanodegree-Program) for a live preview of the example above.
Hope this trick may help someone :).

[image: Example of using a gif instead of using the unsupported video in the markdown]

Answer (score 1):

Actually not only youtube, using a little trick you can upload any videos, even directly from your computer. To do that,

- you can create an **Issue** and simply drag the video file in it
- I always prefer a **thumbnail**, to do so, **snapshot** a picture from the video and drag it like previous step
- you have now two `urls` from the video and image
- use the urls as: `[![img_tag](https://image-url.png)](https://video-url.mp4)`
- e.g.,

> [image: im1]

- simply close the **issue** now (if you want)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<iframe width="500" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: It may work on github pages, but not the github readme.md

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to embed a video on a GitHub page all you need to do is go to the youtube video, click on share, copy the embed code (it should look like this)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z7PExj_v-ZU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and paste it to your markdown page.

Comment: Can confirm this works on markdown renderers that support embedded video.

Comment: This doesn't work on regular GitHub README's, on GitHub itself.  And it also doesn't work on GitHub wiki pages, on GitHub itself.  Tested and tried with my own project. :-)  jz