# Is it possible to embed Youtube/Vimeo videos in Markdown using a C# Markdown library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, youtube, markdown

I'm writing a web app in .NET MVC4 and would like to use Markdown.  I understand there are a few open source C# Markdown libraries, but I haven't found one that obviously supports embedding youtube or Vimeo videos inside Markdown text.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: [markdown-youtube](https://github.com/Exyht/markdown-youtube/tree/master) is in JS & PHP. I think you can easily do something like this in C#.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

## The Solution using *Standard Markdown* ( *not iFrame!* )

Using an iframe is ***not*** the "*obvious*" solution... *especially* if the Markdown parser (or publishing platform) you are using does not support inlining content from a different website ... Instead you can "fake it" by including a ***valid linked-image*** in your Markdown file, using this format:

`[![IMAGE ALT TEXT](http://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/0.jpg)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE "Video Title")`

### Explanation of the Markdown

If this markdown snippet looks complicated, break it down into two parts:

an image
`![image alt text](http//example.io/link-to-image)`
wrapped in a link
`[link text](http//example.io/my-link "link title")`

## Example using Valid Markdown and YouTube Thumbnail:

[image: Everything Is AWESOME]

We are sourcing the ***thumbnail*** image *directly* from YouTube and linking to the actual video, so when the person clicks the image/thumbnail they will be taken to the video.

### Code:

`[![Everything Is AWESOME](https://img.youtube.com/vi/StTqXEQ2l-Y/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y "Everything Is AWESOME")`

***OR*** If you want to give readers a ***visual cue*** that the image/thumbnail is actually a *playable* video, take your own screenshot of the video in YouTube and use that as the thumbnail instead.

## Example using Screenshot with Video Controls as Visual Cue:

[image: Everything Is AWESOME]

### Code:

`[![Everything Is AWESOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3ceS.png)](https://youtu.be/StTqXEQ2l-Y?t=35s "Everything Is AWESOME")`

### ***Clear* Advantages**

While this requires a couple of extra steps (**a**) *taking the screenshot* of the video and (**b**) *uploading it* so you can use the image as your thumbnail it does have **3 *clear* advantages**:

1. The person reading your markdown (or resulting html page) has a **visual cue** telling them they can watch the video (*video controls encourage clicking*)
2. You can chose a **specific frame** in the video to use as the thumbnail (thus making your content **more engaging**)
3. You can **link to a specific time** in the video from which play will start when the linked-image is clicked. (in our case from 35 seconds)

Taking a screenshot takes a few seconds and there are keyboard shortcuts for each OS which copy the screenshot to your clipboard which means you can *paste* it for even faster upload.

## Not *Only* `C#`

And since this is **100% Standard** markdown, it **works *everywhere*** (*not just for the `C#` parser!*) ... try it on GitHub, Redit or Ghost!

## Vimeo

This approach also works with Vimeo videos

### Example

[image: Little red ridning hood]

### Code

```
[![Little red ridning hood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRlR.png)](https://vimeo.com/3514904 "Little red riding hood - Click to Watch!")
```

## Notes:

- *How* to **take screenshot**: http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ (***all platforms***!)
- **Upload Thumbnail Image**: Once you've taken your screenshot you can **drag-and-drop** it into [**imgur.com**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3xiA.jpg) to **upload** and immediately use it as your thumbnail; *couldn't be easier*!
- YouTube thumbnail info: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)
- Markdown format borrowed/modified/expanded from: [Embed a YouTube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804820/embed-a-you-tube-video)

Comment: This is an ingenious solution. Simple and gets the job done. It even made me laugh when I first read it. Nice work.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [inline HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) to embed your video.

```
# this is a *markdown* document

<iframe  title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TheVideoID?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

with a **youtube** video embedded
```

Comment: Ahh my mistake - the url must be http://www.youtube.com/v/theVideoID?html5=1 ... or rather, use the API, not the web site with the watch parameter

Comment: Very nice but using that iframe breaks the same origin policy. This post has the solution to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin

Comment: I believe this is the ideal correct answer since, as you point out, Markdown has always allowed HTML literals.  Grab the 'embed' snippet that YouTube kindly provides (currently in the 'Share' options below a video). The snippet uses an `<iframe>` as in your example, but also has an 'embed' URL which makes visual and usability improvements for embedding. Of course, this assumes that your Markdown renderer *allows* HTML literals.

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-mUJnKI3ipI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Markdown won't let you embed videos, Basically the answers posted here are explaining to have a image link, which is clearly not what an embed means. So the answer to whether you can embed a video or not is "NO You can't".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the HTML5 `<video>` element. Someone tell me if this doesn't work.

(Just spotted this, many years late :-) , as I want to add video support to my md2pptx Markdown to PowerPoint open source tool.)

Answer (score -6):

What about the syntax for embedding image, applied to other media?

```
![MyImage](https://example.com/image.png)
```

Oembed is interesting to make embedding easier: users just have to paste the URL instead of an iframe code.
For video, it could be

```
![MyVideo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TheVideoID)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You can do something similar to link to the video with one of its image previews:

`[![Video Label](http://img.youtube.com/vi/TheVideoID/0.jpg)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TheVideoID)`