# Can you embed a YouTube video in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook, youtube, jupyter

I am trying to embed a YouTube video into an existing Jupyter notebook, using the `embed` code and an `iframe`.  I have seen a few other solutions where they use a code cell which is then executed - but this is not desirable, as outlined below.

I would like to embed the `iframe` directly into a markdown cell in the notebooks.  This way we can re-use the same notebook markdown with a variety of kernels without having to change the code cells.

Do you know if this is possible or not?  Does it require installing any additional tools (e.g. Node.js)?

---

For a minimal example, suppose I wanted to embed this code in a markdown cell:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jZ952vChhuI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

If I include it in a markdown cell as follows:

````
# My Markdown Video

This is where the video should go:

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jZ952vChhuI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>```

But it's not here.
````

However, when this markdown cell is rendered (run) the `iframe` does not show up; it's just a blank.  It will display if you try to print the notebook, but it's not interactive.

Comment: You've already seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862668/8508004 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69363841/8508004 ?

Answer (score 1):

Not in markdown but you can use `%%html` at the top of a code block that doesn't mind what kernel type you're using to embed the video:

```
%%html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jZ952vChhuI" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This is OK, but it will only work with kernels that support the ``%%html`` magic (like the IPython kernel), which was the issue I had with the code blocks; thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: When I add this HTML to a markdown cell, this `iframe` works without the magic command. Thanks for the gist.