# How to add a linked image to a video in GitHub README?

Tags: github, hyperlink, youtube, embed, readme

I've been trying to embed a screen cast of my Java project in the GutHub README of the project's repository. The solution I came across was to use a [Linked image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804820/embed-a-you-tube-video) but the link I created doesn't show the thumbnail or link to the video.

I've followed the solution in the Stackoverflow question to the letter, but can't see where the mistake is. I first got the thumbnail and video link which I checked individually, both are valid.

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong with adding this linked image?
The below screenshot shows how its showing on GitHub:

[image: Linked image impl]

This is the link I created:

```
[![Fibonacci RMI Java EE](http://img.youtube.com/vi/nX_inqaAzOI/0.jpg)]
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX_inqaAzOI&feature=youtu.be&hd=1 "RMI Fibonacci Java")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that you have split the markdown code into 2 lines. The following code seems to work fine:

```
[![Fibonacci RMI Java EE](http://img.youtube.com/vi/nX_inqaAzOI/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX_inqaAzOI&feature=youtu.be&hd=1 "RMI Fibonacci Java")
```

Comment: Tried that exactly as one line, but it still gives the same result. No thumbnail shown. Not sure why as it seems to be exactly as in the SO solution.

Comment: That's very strange. I tried this out in a readme in a temporary repo that I have on Github, and it showed exactly what you seemed to want...

Comment: Yeah not sure why, I'll play around with it a bit more, and accept the answer if it works.