# youtube thumbnail doesn't appear in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson, video-thumbnails

I'm new to Jupyter notebook (I'm using Python in iBM Watson Studio) and now I'm working on uploading a youtube video. The link shows up fine but the thumbnail just looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRWtp.png

This is the code that I have:

```
[![Elephant poaching in Kenya](https://img.youtube.com/vi/watch?v=CO5Fl5tTDVY/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CO5Fl5tTDVY)
```

I based this code on the explanations given in the following links: 1) [How can I embed a YouTube video on GitHub wiki pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804820/how-can-i-embed-a-youtube-video-on-github-wiki-pages)
2) https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet

I've tried replacing 0 in the link for the image with 1, 2,, 3, and default. I also tried writing "Elephant poaching in Kenya" after the URL for the video (I saw that in an explanation), but neither of those things solved the problem...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'watch?v='

```
[![Elephant poaching in Kenya](https://img.youtube.com/vi/CO5Fl5tTDVY/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CO5Fl5tTDVY)
```

will work