# how to add instagram preview url on README.md in github?

Tags: git, github, markdown, preview, readme

I tried adding instagram preview URL like [Youtube preview URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945782/13592049) in readme.md in github by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079387/13592049)

```
> https://img.youtube.com/vi/<VIDEO ID>/0.jpg

[![pygame](https://img.youtube.com/vi/FfWpgLFMI7w/0.jpg)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w"pygame")
```

It works for youtube video but what about instagram and facebook videos??

The youtube preview URL works but the instagram preview doesn't work, i tried everthing,can anyone please help me..

```
[![pygame](http://img.instagram.com/p/B_LXgD0Hzgx/0.jpg)]((https://www.instagram.com/p/B_LXgD0Hzgx/)
```

[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmxYt.png)

Comment: You cannot use a preview link like that for Instagram because such a link doesn't exist. Either you need to use Instagram's API and find out what the image source is, or find it in browser using the developer tools. I have found out the link for you for that image and it is [this](https://scontent-bom1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/93365649_1664813790338943_1719279697222189407_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-bom1-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=A-af_LV2gPUAX_9gsqZ&oh=94992ed2aca4fb6fd5cd4ac2d3588f6a&oe=5EDC8079)

Comment: Replace the link that I have provided in place of the link that you have used in your readme

Comment: @MadhuBhat thanks for your comment, it does solved my issue, please refer me the developer tool you used to find out the instagram api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more about the Instagram feature rather than a problem of Markdown/GitHub/Git. You can use the Instagram API for such purposes.I hope that solves your problem. I have not looked into detail but I think [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) might solve your problem.

From what I have inferred you may do: `GET /{ig-user-id}/media`
to get the media data of a user (this does not include IGTV videos).

A tip is to search for an API of the service you are aiming for. For instance, popular services like LinkedIn, Twitter, GoogleMaps, YouTube and StackOverFlow have their own APIs which serve various purposes and can be tailored specially as per your needs.

I hope this solves your problem!

Best