# How do I embed a video on GitHub?

Tags: github, video, youtube, embedded-resource, youtube-iframe-api

I created this .md file that hosts all the videos for our Open Source project. I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804820/how-can-i-embed-a-youtube-video-on-github-wiki-pages) that provided the code below for adding YouTube video links along with Thumbnails on GitHub:

`[![Img alt text](https://img.youtube.com/vi/YouTube_video_ID/0.jpg)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YouTube_video_ID)`

When you click the image, it redirects to the YouTube page. However, I wanted to know if anyone knows a way to embed the video so that the contributors stay on GitHub when they watch a video?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot embed a video into markdown in GitHub. Clear and simple: nope :(

Comment: Consider making a page via `github.io` to promote your project. The link should be something like `YourRepositoryName.github.io` and add an html code with Youtube iframe.