# Embed Youtube video in GitHub readme restructuredtext (rst)

Tags: github, video, youtube, embed, restructuredtext

How can I do that? I found [this](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/862) and [this](https://github.com/github/markup/pull/526), saying that raw HTML should be supported. However, I tried this, which [does not work](https://github.com/albertz/py-tui-editor/blob/a97e6a357248ee4dcd2c518a305ca69e35105a01/README.rst):

```
.. raw:: html

    <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zIFMyBkYwqg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

[This is a related question for readme markdown (md) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279611/how-to-embed-a-video-into-github-readme-md/). For markdown, raw HTML or video support seems not supported, so they embed just an image with a link to the video. If a video is not possible, then I would like to do the same, but also then, the question is how.

Comment: "For markdown, raw HTML or video support seems not supported, so they embed just an image with a link to the video. If a video is not possible, then I would like to do the same, but also then, the question is how." [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079387/7123660) seems to be your backup solution.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison This is the answer for markdown, but I'm asking about restructuredtext here. Although I guess it's simple to translate. But it would be helpful for others to have this as an answer here.

Comment: Oh sorry I read too quickly your last sentences and I thought that a markdown backup solution was fine in your case.

Comment: I added the translated solution [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73581315/7123660).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is in reStructuredText the code for embedding an image with a link to the YouTube video.

```
.. image:: https://img.youtube.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE/maxresdefault.jpg
    :alt: IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE
    :target: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID_HERE
```

Comment: Using `.../maxresdefault.jpg` as the image is probably better, right?

Comment: Indeed I just tried and modified my answer accordingly.