# How to render the YouTube video link in my markdown editor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to render a YouTube link in my markdown editor. The link is given blow,
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ymixpC53c-s/

I tried using markdownToHtml() to render. I need to render in markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862696/5956799)

Insert a Video is not possible. But you can look it like.

Crate a image of the video you want with this generator [here](https://yt-embed.herokuapp.com/)

**Instruction:**

```
[![DESCRIPTION](https://yt-embed.herokuapp.com/embed?v=[VIDEO_ID])](YOUTUBE_LINK)
```

**Example:**

[image: Markdown Crash Course]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).