# Github Top-Level Project Page

Tags: github

Is it possible to publish a project page to http://username.github.com/ instead of http://username.github.com/projectname?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a repository called username.github.com and it will automatically be used as your top-level page.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since April 2013 ("[New GitHub Pages domain: github.io](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io)"):

- User Pages repositories may now be named using the new **`username/username.github.io`**
- Existing User Pages repositories named like username/username.github.com do not need to be renamed and will continue to be published indefinitely.
- If both a username.github.io and a username.github.com repository exists, the username.github.io version wins.

So the solution is still valid, but be aware that:

> If your Pages site was previously served from a `username.github.com` domain, **all traffic will be redirected to the new `username.github.io` location indefinitely**, so you won't have to change any links.
>   For example, newmerator.github.com now redirects to newmerator.github.io.