# Convention for including video on Github

Tags: github

What's the most common convention for including some informational videos in a Github Readme or other Markdown file? I would like users to visit my Github repo and be able to watch some short videos embedded in my files while browsing my repo.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279611/how-to-embed-a-video-into-github-readme-md