# Add audio in Github readme.md

Tags: audio, github, readme

Is there a way to add an audio bar in the Github readme.md? I want to be able to play a certain mp3 file directly through the readme.md, rather than be directed to some soundcloud or youtube link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update May 2021: as  I already reported in "[How to embed a video into GitHub README.md?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279746/6309)", "[Video uploads now is generally available](https://github.blog/2021-05-13-video-uploads-available-github/)"

[image: video upload]

---

Original answer 20217:

No, as [I documented before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279746/6309), an [`<audio>` element](https://github.com/etianen/html5media/wiki/embedding-audio) (or video) is not supported in GitHub Markdown.

For video, a workaround is to use an animated GIF, but for audio, having a placeholder linking to the actual audio seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 9):

As of [May 2021](https://github.blog/2021-05-13-video-uploads-available-github/), GitHub supports video uploads, and *sort of* supports audio uploads. While you cannot directly upload `.wav` or `.mp3` files to GitHub, uploading a `.mp4` or `.mov` file containing only audio gives an (albeit poorly-formatted) audio player:
[image: Audio player]

You can convert `.wav` and `.mp4` files into compatible video files with [freeconvert.com](https://www.freeconvert.com/wav-to-mov) or any similar converter.