# Add Video To Readme Using Git LFS

Tags: github, git-lfs, readme

I added a video greater than 100MB to my repo using Git LFS. How would I show the video on the project's readme besides linking the url path?

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279611/how-to-embed-a-video-into-github-readme-md) to similar question.

Comment: No I'm wondering how to show the video I directly uploaded to my repo.