# Can GitHub Pages automatically process GitHub video assets?

Tags: github, markdown, embed

I am aware of several other questions on the seemingly related topic (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945782/5252007)), but I would like to know if or how the following can be achieved.

**Setup**

- Suppose you have the following sample **GitHub repository**, i.e., [mihaiconstantin/github-asssets-and-pages](https://github.com/mihaiconstantin/github-asssets-and-pages/).
- It contains a single `README.md` file with a text and **an external link to a video**, i.e.,:

  - https://github.com/mihaiconstantin/github-asssets-and-pages/assets/20051042/764d3ae0-c3d8-4b30-97c5-b6a8bec805d5
  - The video `URI` was obtained by the mighty drag-an-drop action in the `README.md` in edit mode on GitHub.
  - When accessed, it resolves to the storage location somewhere in the `AWS` `S3` storage, e.g.,:

    - https://github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com/20051042/241174616-764d3ae0-c3d8-4b30-97c5-b6a8bec805d5.mp4
- The corresponding **GitHub Pages** `URL` for this repository is the following:

  - https://mihaiconstantin.com/github-asssets-and-pages/

**Observed Behavior**

- When I access the GitHub repository page, it renders the video `URI` as a `<video/>` element in `HTML`.

  - This seems only to be the case for assets uploaded via GitHub, i.e., other external links do not appear to get the same treatment. For clarity, here is the generated `HTML`:

```
<video 
    src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20051042/241174616-764d3ae0-c3d8-4b30-97c5-b6a8bec805d5.mp4" 
    data-canonical-src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20051042/241174616-764d3ae0-c3d8-4b30-97c5-b6a8bec805d5.mp4" 
    ...   
>
</video>
```

- However, when I access the GitHub Pages for the repository, the `URI` is displayed as plain text, which makes sense.

**Desired Behavior**

Is there any way to get the GitHub Pages to treat the `URI` in the `README.md` the same way as GitHub does (i.e., to render it as a `<video/>` element?

My current workaround is to replace the `URI` in the `README.md` with the generated `</video>` element, as seen on the [`video-tag`](https://github.com/mihaiconstantin/github-asssets-and-pages/tree/video-tag) branch of the sample repository.